# Jquery assign new property, based on another

Tags: jquery, properties, domready

In my `$().ready()` area, I want to add a property to an object, based on another property of it. it should be done **before** any event on the object.

e.g:

```
<input value="text" />

$().ready(function(){
  $("input").newProp = ???
});
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just read off whatever property you want to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").prop("newPropName", $("input").prop("propertyToCopy"))
});
```

If you want to add a property without use of `$.prop()`, then you would have to directly access the HTML element:

```
$("input")[0].newPropName = $("input")[0][propName];
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to add an attribute, just a property to the object.

Comment: That is a property. Adding an attribute would be done throught `$.attr`.

Comment: Oh ... seems like i got it wrong. thought that `prop` replaced `attr`, and `attr` was deprecated. You are correct. thanks!